# Вывод информаций из JSON в HTML 2

Tags: php, html, json

Предыдущее решение: [РЕШЕНИЕ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860385/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json-%D0%B2-html/860390?noredirect=1#comment1388290_860390)

Внутри есть внутри tags и сustom_fields, как вытаскивать name и value (Например: Адрес доставки: Адрес; Телефон: Номер: Количество: кол-во.) Спасибо!

```html
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/v2/leads?status=18468961",
            "method": "get"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 7612939,
                "name": "Доставка на Дзержинского  76",
                "responsible_user_id": 2170399,
                "created_by": 2170399,
                "created_at": 1527060038,
                "updated_at": 1527116634,
                "account_id": 18334111,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {},
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "id": 136663,
                        "name": "ЗАКАЗ ИЗ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 192403,
                        "name": "ЦЕНТР"
                    }
                ],
                "custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 379810,
                        "name": "Количество",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 379905,
                        "name": "Адрес доставки",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "Дзержинского  76"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 389997,
                        "name": "Телефон",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "89659979796"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    }
                ],
                "status_id": 18468961,
                "sale": 0,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "contacts": {},
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 980719,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=980719",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=7612939",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 8317497,
                "name": "Доставка на Дзержинского 51",
                "responsible_user_id": 2170399,
                "created_by": 2170399,
                "created_at": 1531722164,
                "updated_at": 1531972399,
                "account_id": 18334111,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {},
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "id": 136663,
                        "name": "ЗАКАЗ ИЗ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 192403,
                        "name": "ЦЕНТР"
                    }
                ],
                "custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 379810,
                        "name": "Количество",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 379905,
                        "name": "Адрес доставки",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "Дзержинского 51"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 389997,
                        "name": "Телефон",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "79244694163"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380773,
                        "name": "Подъезд",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380777,
                        "name": "Этаж",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "7"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380781,
                        "name": "Квартира",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "89"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    }
                ],
                "status_id": 18468961,
                "sale": 0,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "contacts": {},
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 980719,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=980719",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=8317497",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 8253299,
                "name": "Доставка на Жорницкого",
                "responsible_user_id": 2170399,
                "created_by": 2170399,
                "created_at": 1531350142,
                "updated_at": 1531972433,
                "account_id": 18334111,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {},
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "id": 136663,
                        "name": "ЗАКАЗ ИЗ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 192403,
                        "name": "ЦЕНТР"
                    }
                ],
                "custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 379810,
                        "name": "Количество",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 379905,
                        "name": "Адрес доставки",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "Жорницкого"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 389997,
                        "name": "Телефон",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "89142760010"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380773,
                        "name": "Подъезд",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380777,
                        "name": "Этаж",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "7"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380781,
                        "name": "Квартира",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "53"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    }
                ],
                "status_id": 18468961,
                "sale": 120,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "contacts": {},
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 980719,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=980719",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=8253299",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 8044599,
                "name": "Доставка на Борисовка 3 в1",
                "responsible_user_id": 2170399,
                "created_by": 2170399,
                "created_at": 1530177493,
                "updated_at": 1531972598,
                "account_id": 18334111,
                "is_deleted": false,
                "main_contact": {},
                "group_id": 0,
                "company": {},
                "closed_at": 0,
                "closest_task_at": 0,
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "id": 136663,
                        "name": "ЗАКАЗ ИЗ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 192403,
                        "name": "ЦЕНТР"
                    }
                ],
                "custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 379810,
                        "name": "Количество",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 379905,
                        "name": "Адрес доставки",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "Борисовка 3 в1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 389997,
                        "name": "Телефон",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "89142717267"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380773,
                        "name": "Подъезд",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380777,
                        "name": "Этаж",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 380781,
                        "name": "Квартира",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "is_system": false
                    }
                ],
                "status_id": 18468961,
                "sale": 360,
                "loss_reason_id": 0,
                "contacts": {},
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 980719,
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/v2/pipelines?id=980719",
                            "method": "get"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/api/v2/leads?id=8044599",
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: А `tags` зачем если все берется из `сustom_fields`?

Comment: Для примера хотел, а так необязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($out, TRUE);
foreach ($json['_embedded']['items'] as $value) {
    //  Выводим ID, NAME, SALE
    echo $value['id'] . ', ' . $value['name'] . ', ' . $value['sale'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-----' . PHP_EOL;
    //  Перебираем TAGS
    echo implode(': ', array_column($value['tags'], 'name')) . PHP_EOL;
    echo '-----' . PHP_EOL;
    //  Перебираем CUSTOM_FIELDS
    $ARRAY = array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]['value'];}, array_column($value['custom_fields'], 'values', 'name'));
    foreach ($ARRAY as $a_key => $a_value) {
        echo $a_key . ': ' . $a_value . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '-------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Результат будет такой (например для последнего):

```
8044599, Доставка на Борисовка 3 в1, 360
-----
ЗАКАЗ ИЗ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ: ЦЕНТР
-----
Количество: 3
Адрес доставки: Борисовка 3 в1
Телефон: 89142717267
Подъезд: 1
Этаж: 2
Квартира: 5
-------------------------
```

Ну а там уже если не все поля нужны, а определенные, то думаю вы сообразите